# What kind of connector does this charger use?

Tags: connector

I've tried without any success to identify this type of connector, does anyone know what type it is?

[image: Charger connector]

I'm planning to make a charge limiter for an electric scooter and I'd like to place it in between the charger and the scooter, to not mess with the warranty, so I'm trying to find a male and female connector for it.

It's a 3 pin locking connector and so far I was able to find this which seems to match the appearance of what I have: [LCSC - Neutrik-NAC3FCB](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Circular-Connectors-Cable-Connectors_Neutrik-NAC3FCB_C368515.html).

I'd like to know if this is a standard connector or it's some obscure one that I'll have to get wherever I can get it from.

Comment: Could it be an XLR connector? I know Neutrik makes a bunch of those, and the most standard XLR is a three-pin locking connector that's widely available.

Comment: Can you include a photo of the pin side?

Comment: XLR 3 pin connector.  At least that is what the [internet](https://novi.kupujemprodajem.com/foto-aparati-i-kamere/baterije-punjaci-i-gripovi/58-8v-2a-punjac-ms-energy-x10-52v-trotinet-ebike-skuter/oglas/90796118) says.

Comment: Definitely _not_ an XLR. XLR connectors don't have those alignment tabs on the outside of the barrel.

Comment: @colintd I can't include a photo of the pins because it's in service with a possibly dead battery cell. That's the reason of trying to limit the charge to ~85%, I have the bad habit of plugging it in and forgetting it plugged in, and it seems to have a not so smart BMS that does nothing to conserve battery life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a knock-off of a Neutrik NAC3FXXB-W-S.

https://www.neutrik.com/en/product/nac3fxxb-w-s

[image: NAC3FCB]

{Neutrik}

Answer (score 0):

It might be a [Neutrik powerCON TRUE1](https://www.neutrik.us/en-us/neutrik/products/powercon/powercon-true1) which has been replaced by the newer (and compatible) [Neutrik powerCON TRUE1 TOP](https://www.neutrik.us/en-us/neutrik/products/powercon/powercon-true1-top). Specifically, it looks like a locking female cable connector, such as [NAC3FX-W-TOP](https://www.neutrik.us/en-us/product/nac3fx-w-top).